# Declare headless Fragment in layout XML?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

It it possible to declare a headless `Fragment` in layout XML?  Like perhaps with an attribute that tells the inflater not to expect a `View`?  When I try it like this:

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.HeadlessFragment"
    android:id="@+id/headless_fragment" />
```

...not entirely unexpectedly, it crashes with this:

```
07-08 15:41:32.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5943): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.example.HeadlessFragment did not create a view.
```

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to create a holder for fragments? If so, you can use a `ViewGroup` for that, and replace your fragments programmatically.

Comment: @EvanBashir I'm using a [retained headless fragment](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) for some short-lived background processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***No, you can't***

When you declare a fragment in a tag, you are saying:
"The following fragment will be added with this id to this parent view."

Following this statement, a headless fragment will be added to a no parent view, so it is not working. You can have a look at the API to add a new fragment, it will need a tag or a container, and xml fragments make sense on the second option.

Beside that, just for code and file economy, if you want to have only a fragment in an xml, it makes more sense to do a `new WhateverFragment()` than a `LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(...);`